# Best Practices in Installing Python Modules on Windows

Tags: python, module

I'm trying to install openpyxl and I haven't the clue how to install it. I have my C:\Python27...but what directory do I put it in? FYI, I'm a complete noob to modules and what not...I appreciate your help.

I have put in the lib and libs directory of python and try installing it to no avail. Here is a link to the site I got my download... http://pythonhosted.org/openpyxl/.

Basically, I extracted the file and move it to the lib directory. However, I cannot import it.

Comment: Might be easier to use pip or easy_install and do `pip install openpyxl` or `easy_install openpyxl`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's even easier when the package is on the Python Package Index (PyPI). Just install `pip` and use it to download and install the package and all its dependencies.

https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pip

Answer (score 5):

There is a `setup.py` script provided. Typically you run:

```
python setup.py install
```

From the directory were you've downloaded the library, and it gets installed automatically.

Consider also more convenient tools that manage installing Python libraries in general like [pip](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pip) or [easy_install](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/setuptools) mentioned in other answers and comments.